# What is the @type annotation in hiberante for?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have a mapping containing the following piece of code:

```
@Type(
    type = "commons.db.hibernate.GenericEnumUserType",
    parameters = {
            @Parameter(
                name  = "enumClass",
                value = "commons.db.entity.Currency"),
            @Parameter(
                name  = "identifierMethod",
                value = "getValue"),
            @Parameter(
                name  = "valueOfMethod",
                value = "getByValue")
            }
)
@Column(name="currency_id")
private Currency currency;
```

where Currency is the following enumeration:

```
public enum Currency {

    FUN(0),
    USD(1),
    RUB(2),
    UAH(3),
    EUR(5);

    private int value;

    Currency (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Currency getByValue(int value) {
        for (Currency currency : Currency.values()) {
            if (value == currency.getValue()) {
                return currency;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Th thing is I can't get the point of such usage the annotation. What does this one actually do?

Comment: It tells Hibernate how to map from your enum to the database value and back (and the default implementation probably does the same, so it may be a bit redundant here, but useful if the mapping from int is non-standard).

Comment: @Thilo What does parameter-annotation do in that case?

Comment: It tells Hibernate 1) which enum class to use 2) what method to use to get the int value 3) what method to use to get an enum from the int value  (you need the @Parameter to group each name and value together in the parameters array).

Comment: @Thilo That's the name parameter may have only fixed set of values. I mean we can't write something like `name="aoliuhfga"`, can we?

Comment: No, it is kind of the opposite: if you can fix a set of names, you don't need *Parameter, you could do enumClass="...", identifierMethod=".." directly in *Type. This parameters is a way to pass in any data that the particular Type may need. Kind of like JavaBean vs Map to give configuration.